# Datables - hide data until search

Tags: datatables

I'd like for my page to initially load with just a search box, and then when someone begins to search that is when the table appears.

My example table is below:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            responsive: true
        } );
    } );
</script>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th class="none">Branch</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 1</td>
            <td>Test test test</td>
            <td>ABC</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 2</td>
            <td>Test test test</td>
            <td>DEF</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Test 3</td>
            <td>Test test test</td>
            <td>GHI</td>
        </tr>          
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

Comment: To get you to the answer you need take a look at how to Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

yes it can be done using ajax call and i suppose you use php.
For example, you can generate a table everytime you press any char, populating the table with the results or using a button to search the keyword you type on the input field.
Example with ajax and php:

```
var search_string = $('#id_of_the_input_box').val();
$.ajax({
    url:"php_file.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{action:action},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
}
```

and the php code using PDO

```
$search_string = $_POST["string"];
$result = '';
$query = $connection->prepare(" select * from table where name = '%".search_string."' ";
$query->execute();
$query_results->query->fetchAll;
if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
   $result = '
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#example').DataTable( {
                  responsive: true
               });
            });
            <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
              YOUR TABLE ROWS HERE
            </table>
   ';

   // foreach loop to populate the table example
   foreach ($query_results as $row) {
        $result.= '
            <tr>
              <td>'.$row["table_column_name_1"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["table_column_name_1"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["table_column_name_1"].'</td>
              <td>'.$row["table_column_name_1"].'</td>
        '
   } else {
            echo "No results";
          }
}

// echo the generated table as ajax response
echo $result;
```

Hope you have caught the idea with this example.

Comment: Hi, I'm not too familiar with PHP, but I am actually pulling items from a SharePoint list (about 60 total items). My call looks like this - 
`function LoadZipCodes(state)
{
        var call = $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('All BEMS Applications')/items?"+
"$select=Title,System_x0020_Name,ID,Tags,Description&$top=5000",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
       
        });`
Would this work with your method?

Comment: Essentially you are getting data in json format and your data seems to come from selected items, i'm not sure if $select = Title,System... is a query or is just a kind of filtering existing data. If you don't know how data are processed by sharepoint, you can try to view the results using developer tools of mozilla or chrome browser and to understand the json structure and pass the json to my method. May be a link to see it live would help me too.